# Pokeapi pokemonDetails.map is not a function & FIXED [Module '"react-router-dom"' has no exported member 'RouteComponentProps' ]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, match, pokeapi

I am working with the Pokeapi using React and TypeScript. While fetching data to show all Pokemon on one side, everything is working fine. But when clicking on a specific Pokemon to show their details, I get 2 errors.

UPDATE: FIXED! #1 Error: I cannot use {match} because Module '"react-router-dom"' has no exported member 'RouteComponentProps'. I used this in a ReactJS project a few months ago and everything worked fine.

#2 Error: When mapping throw each Pokemon, the error pokemonDetails.map is not a function appears, while working with map in the other Component (showing all Pokemon on one page), everything works fine.

Here is my **App.js Component** using Router:

```
import Pokedex from './Pokedex';
import Pokemon from './Pokemon';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Pokedex />} />
      <Route path='/pokemon/:id' element={<Pokemon />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my **Pokedex Component** (showing all Pokemon on one side):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';

const Pokedex = () => {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPokedex();
  }, []);

  const getPokedex = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151');
      const { results } = await res.json();
      const pokedex = results.map((pokemon: any, index: number) => {
        const paddedId = ('00' + (index + 1)).slice(-3);
        const image = `https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/${paddedId}.png`;
        return { ...pokemon, image };
      });
      setPokemon(pokedex);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      {loading ? (
        'Fetching Pokemon...'
      ) : (
        <Row>
          {pokemon.map((pokemon: any, index: number) => (
            <Col key={index} xs={1} sm={1} md={1} lg={1} xl={1}>
              <a href={`/pokemon/${index + 1}`}>
                <img src={pokemon.image} alt={pokemon.name} />
                <p>
                  {index + 1}.<span>{pokemon.name}</span>
                </p>
              </a>
            </Col>
          ))}
        </Row>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Pokedex;
```

UPDATE: Here is the **Pokemon Component** (for showing details of each Pokemon):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Pokemon = () => {
  const [pokemonDetails, setPokemonDetails] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    getPokemon(id);
  }, [id]);

  const getPokemon = async (id: string | undefined) => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`);
      const pokemon = await res.json();
      const paddedId = ('00' + id).slice(-3);
      pokemon.image = `https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/${paddedId}.png`;
      setPokemonDetails(pokemon);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <h1>Pokemon</h1>
      {loading ? (
        'Fetching Pokemon...'
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h2>{pokemonDetails.name}</h2>
          <h2>{pokemonDetails.id}</h2>
          <img src={pokemonDetails.image} alt={pokemon.Detailsname} />
          <p>
            {pokemonDetails.types.map((type: any, index: number) => (
              <p key={index}>{type.type.name}</p>
            ))}
          </p>
        </div>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Pokemon;
```

The API with the "id" should return this
https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1

And here is my **package.json file** in case you need it:

```
  "name": "pokemon",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.11",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your App.js?

Comment: Could you show what data is the API returning?

Comment: @TanishqVyas The App.js is the first code I added here.

Comment: @TanishqVyas thanks for pointing out the return value of the API. It is an object, so no way to use map function here. I updated the pokemon component, and have now a different error of: ReferenceError: pokemon is not defined. Also, when I set useState({}) to an object, the error Typeerror Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}' occurs.

Comment: [Result of API](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1) @TanishqVyas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for typescript, I had to declare the type of the state to *any*, now the fetching works.

```
const [pokemonDetails, setPokemonDetails] = useState<any>([]);
```

Answer (score 2):

In `react-router-dom` v6 there are no longer [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) (*i.e. no `history`, `location`, or `match` props*) like the `Route` components had in RRDv5. In v6 you should use the React hooks to access the matched route's match params.

1. Use the `Link` component instead of a raw anchor (`<a />`) tag to link to the specific Pokemon page.

   ```
   import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

   ...

   {pokemon.map((pokemon: any, index: number) => (
     <Col key={index} xs={1} sm={1} md={1} lg={1} xl={1}>
       <Link to={`/pokemon/${index + 1}`}>
         <img src={pokemon.image} alt={pokemon.name} />
         <p>
           {index + 1}.<span>{pokemon.name}</span>
         </p>
       </Link>
     </Col>
   ))}
   ```
2. Use `useParams` hook to get the matched `id` match param from the path.

   ```
   import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

   const Pokemon = () => {
     const [pokemonDetails, setPokemonDetails] = useState([]);
     const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

     const { id } = useParams();

     useEffect(() => {
       getPokemon(id);
     }, [id]);

     const getPokemon = async (id: number) => {
       try {
         const res = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`);
         const pokemon = await res.json();
         const paddedId = ('00' + id).slice(-3);
         pokemon.image = `https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/${paddedId}.png`;
         setPokemonDetails(pokemon);
         setLoading(false);
       } catch (err) {
         console.error(err);
       }
     };

     return (
       ...
     );
   };
   ```